# how to do Implementation of Android TvView

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tv

I have started working on Android Smart Tv. I have to make a TvView, I Know Leanback is only library which gives us a lot of stuff to work with Android Smart Tv. Last day i have tried to work with TvView to perform streaming of channels. I have included android-support-Leanback17 .  but still i am getting error That no class definition found. Any Help will be appreciated . i Just want to know that which library support this TvView.
Thanks in Advance

This is my LogCat

```
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:    android.media.tv.TvView
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at    com.example.tvtest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:829)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:596)
  11-27 09:25:10.684: E/AndroidRuntime(16203):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Brother I have edited the question with logcat

Comment: I am creating this TvView Dynamically (Not in XML). i have imported anroid.media.tv.TvView

Comment: it is not more than two lines 

TvView Tv = new TvView(this); 
Tv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100));

Comment: you are not adding your view into layout. you are just creating it

Comment: you can simply do this by giving id to your root layout and reference it in you onCreate, and then youLayout.add(yourView).

Comment: This is not useful, i Know i am not adding this to a parent layout . on your solution i have tried this too . but illogical thing is that its not concerning with the class definition as i am unable to find class definition.  I have tried this from XML too. I know I need any support library. or something else. :(

Comment: @Murtaza Hussain
Well Thank You Brother for your response

Comment: Not at all .. i  have found is to make your own library and port the class of android.media.tv.TvView . :) but porting this class is a big mess :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to allow users to watch content and if so, you will not actually implement a TVView. Google provides the ['Live Channels' app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.tv) which will display channels provided via the TVInputFramework. This app is hidden until an app implementing the TVInputFramework is installed.

Google has now released a [sample app implementing the TVInputFramework](https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-sample-inputs) which will publish channels that can be watched in the Live Channels app.

Documentation outlining the TVInputFramework:
http://developer.android.com/training/tv/tif/index.html

I hope this will at least point you in the right direction even if it doesn't directly answer your question.

Comment: Actually I was required to make a View where user can see any channel currently playing on TV. for that I have done this. I have used libraries provided for interacting with the Hardware. Where I get the Channel frequency then I stream that in the SurfaceView. :)

Comment: @MuhammadAdil does it need URL for every channel to play on the TV ?

Comment: @ralphgabb no actually, i have implemented it for both, for third party cable tv provider and for live streaming as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest everyone to go for this Google sample or implementation for Android TvView:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/TV/

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to add TVVIEw component to your application like this

```
> <android.media.tv.TvView
>             android:id="@+id/dtv_view"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             android:visibility="visible" />
```

And it is possible to tune to particular channgel using below code

```
String channelUrl="content://android.media.tv/channel/"+channelNumber;
mTvView.tune(mInputId, Uri.parse(channelUrl));
```

input id is available in TV database(refering to which source channel is coming from).

If you pass these info to tvview it will start playing.